# How to create aws-load-balancer-controller on specific node in aws EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer, helm3, terraform-provider-helm

I'm trying to install aws-load-balancer-controller in my EKS cluster using terraform (resource "helm_release" "aws_load_balancer_controller").

I want the pod (pod/aws-load-balancer-controller-555d8dcf46-zz6tn) created in this process should be scheduled inside specific node.

I know that nodeSelector and nodeAffinity can be easily used, but I'm using terraform to create resources and not getting option to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do that by providing values to the Helm chart. For example, you can define both `nodeSelector` and `affinity`.

Comment: Also, please add at least the `helm_release` resource as you have it currently so I am sure my answer will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to define the `nodeSelector` or `affinity` you have to use the `values` option [1] for the `helm_release`. So, in your case that would be something like:

```
resource "helm_release" "aws_load_balancer_controller" {
  name       = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  version    = "1.4.3"

  values = [
    file("${path.module}/values.yaml")
  ]
}
```

Then, you would have to create a `values.yaml` file in the same directory:

```yaml
nodeSelector:
  <label_key>: <label_value>
```

where the `<label_key>` and `<label_value>` is the label key value pair for the Node you wish to run the Pod on.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#values

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be highly appreciated it that helped.